# not working as expected events via HTML can't be called in script

Tags: javascript, lwc

HTML:

```html
<body>
  <script type="module" src="./script.js"></script>
  <div>Welcome to my first html page...</div>
  <div id="username">Another div tag</div>
  <p>This is a paragraph</p>
  <h1>Working on JS</h1>
  <button onclick="firstFunction()">Click</button>    
</body>
```

J/S:

```js
function firstFunction() {
  console.log("Hurry")
}
```

Getting error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: firstFunction is not defined

    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:17)

onclick @ index.html:17
```

What might be the cause of this error?

Comment: if I recall ... modules don't add to the global object - try `globalThis.firstFunction = function() {  console.log("Hurry") }`

Answer (score 0):

Don't import the  js script as module. use the following code instead :

```
<script src="./script.js"></script> `
```

Comment: what if they need it to be a module? then what?

Comment: @Sanath.usk then imports will not work in my js script, if I don't do module

Comment: @jaromanda-x if you need to use it as a module, firstly expose the firstFunction inside the script.js module by adding export modified as shown below:
`export firstFunction() {...}`
functions imported through module type are imported into the scope of a single script and aren't available in the global scope.
Hence for it to work you will have to add it as property to window object:
``` lang-js 
<script type="module">
            import{firstFunction} from './script.js';
            window.firstFunction = firstFunction
</script>
```